# Stuttering in Titanfall

Tags: technical-issues, titanfall

Lately I've been experience stuttering in Titanfall, and especially when a lot is happening in game like explosions etc. Both the graphics and sound starts to stutters, and sometimes the display freezes a few seconds, and usually ends up with disconnecting or game exits.

This is what I have done so far:

- Disabled aero in Windows
- Disabled v-sync (read somewhere I had to enable in game before disable through GFX card)
- Disabled Origin in game
- Set +m_rawinput 1 parameters on run
- Installed latest GFX drivers
- Increased GFX fan speeds (game even stutters at 50-60 celsius)
- Increased CPU priority to high

Specs:

[Intel duo E8400 CPU](http://ark.intel.com/products/33910/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E8400-6M-Cache-3_00-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB)

6GB RAM

Radeon HD 5700 GFX (4 gb)

Game used to run fine earlier, but not anymore. Any ideas? My only thoughts was a faulty HDD (even though I found no error on checkdisk), but anyone else have a clue on this?

Comment: it sounds like the new drivers actually breaks some things. Try reverting your drivers back a few revisions or installing beta drivers (riskier, but much easier)

Comment: OK.

So you are having frame rate and crashing due to heavy load. SO! Let's narrow it down.

What is the CPU usage when the game is running when not much is happening? What is the CPU usage at with lots happening?

Sounds like the CPU is struggling.

Comment: My guess, based on no knowledge at all of Titanfall in particular is that some patch introduced new stuff like physics or something, that is CPU heavier (or more exact netcode or anything that would drive CPU usage). This causes your CPU to choke. Measure it in-game as stutters happen. 

Becuase with your specifications, i am seeing that you are already bordering tech so obsolete most games would be unplayable on it. That CPU is due for an upgrade i reckon :)

But to help checking that, please d/l tools to measure in-game CPU use, especially at the point of the stutters.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Origin in game overlay. Worked on a friend's PC who was experiencing a similar problem.

Comment: Forgot to wrote I also disabled Origin in game.